# jQueryでセレクトボックスの値とマッチするaハッシュ要素を取得する

Tags: javascript, jquery

以下のように用意されたセレクトボックスがあり、

```
<select id="data">
  <option value=1>hoge</option>
  <option value=2>fuga</option>
  <option value=3>hogehoge</option>
</select>

<a href="#1">hoge</a>
<a href="#2">fuga</a>
<a href="#3">hogehoge</a>
```

jqueryで値の変化を取得しそれにマッチするアンカーリンクに何かしらの処理をしたいのですが、
どうしてもうまくいきません。例えばセレクトボックスで`'fuga'`が選択されたらfugaのaタグの背景色を変化させる等。

以下jQueryでvalueまでは取得できているコードになります。

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('data').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    /**/
});
});
```

どなたかご教示いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

サンプルを作ってみました。いかがですか。そうではない、という場合はコメントを付けてください。修正します。

```js
$('#selectHash').change(function () {
  var selectedHash = this.value;
  if (selectedHash) {
    var result = $('a')
    .removeClass('hashSelected')
    .filter(function () {
      return this.hash === selectedHash;
    });
    
    // for example, change color
    result.addClass('hashSelected');
  }
});
```

```css
.hashSelected { background-color: rgba(0, 123, 221, 0.5); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://example.com/path/to/content#header">example.com #header</a>
<a href="/local/path/to/content#hIndex">local #hIndex</a>
<a href="#test">#test</a>
<a href="#hIndex">#hIndex</a>

<select id="selectHash">
  <option value="">pls select hash</option>
  <option value="#header">#header</option>
  <option value="#hIndex">#hIndex</option>
  <option value="#test">#test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 有難うございました、.filterの使い方が熟知していませんでしたので大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

タイトルの「aハッシュ要素」と言うのが何のことかよくわからないので、意図を読み違えているかもしれませんが。

href属性値の"#〜"の内容によってa要素を選択したいと言うのであれば、普通に`[]`セレクタが使えるはずです。

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#data').change(function(){ //<-ここは'data'ではなく、'#data'ですよね
    var value = $(this).val();
    var $a = $('a[href="#'+value+'"]');
    //...
  });
});
```